# MySQL put repeat number in a field

Tags: mysql

I did this once before and I have *zero* idea how I accomplished it. This is part of a much bigger process so the why is not worth mentioning.

I have a column in a table that I need to store the number of repeats of the row. i.e.

Table currently looks like this

```
content | repeated
-------------------
aaa     | NULL
bob     | NULL
aaa     | NULL
```

Expected output is to have the table look like this

```
content | repeated
-------------------
aaa     | 2
bob     | 1
aaa     | 2
```

I can get those counts with distinct, or COUNT(*), but I can't for the life of me remember how to get a single query to run against the whole table and update all the records repeated field.

Comment: Unclear. Better show your expected output based on sample input.

Comment: Updated to clarify that sample table data is output

Comment: You want to update your table or want select query?

Comment: Update the table, I need to run mountains of queries against the repeat count so not having to re-do the counting every time by saving the result is the goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE
your_table YT
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   content,
   COUNT(*) total
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY content
) AS t
ON YT.content = t.content
SET YT.repeated = t.total;
```

<kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9baef/1/0)</kbd>
*In demo you'll see data after being updated*

**Explanation:**

- First get `count` for each `content` by the inner select query and
  give it an alias `t`.
- Then make an `inner join` between another alias of your table `YT`
  and `t` on `matching content`.
- Now set the repeated field of `YT` table to the value from `t.total`.

Comment: My hero! Contribution: `your_table AS YT` makes it a bit easier to understand I feel. Also if there isn't a single content field you need to include them in the inner join's select (separated by commas) and in the ON separated by ANDs. This is mostly a note to myself for the next time I forget this at a critical time.

Comment: That's the purpose of `alias`: to make it more readable. Good luck mate!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a subquery to determine the number of repetitions by content, wrap this into another fully meaningless subquery to get around MySQL's limitation on selecting from the table which is being modified, and join this subquery in an update statement on your original table:

```
update yourtable
inner join
    (select *
     from
         (select content, count(*) as repeat
          from yourtable
          group by content
         ) t1
    ) t2 on yourtable.content=t2.content
set yourtable.repeated=t2.repeat
```